# How to show different content in multisite with the network_site_url() function?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, url

I am stuck with the function `network_site_url()` and the `if` statement. I want to show different content via my different Multisite.

Here is the code:

```
$url= network_site_url();

if ($url=='string-url'){

     the_content( __( 'example1 <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'esquire' ) ); }

else{ 

the_content( __( 'example2 <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'esquire' ) );  }
```

In fact the string value of the $url variable must be either `http://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com/it`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [**`get_current_blog_id()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id), [`network_site_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_site_url) is to simply *"Retrieve the site url for the current network."*.

```
switch( get_current_blog_id() )
{
    case 1:
        echo 'main site';
    break;
    case 43:
        echo 'site #43');
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I've tried and it works pretty well.

I found also another way.

```
 global $current_blog;
 if($current_blog-> blog_id == 2){
 //content }
 else{
 //content}
```

Comment: It's [almost exactly the same thing](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/load.php#L674), but without using globals ourselves, letting WP do it. Nice to know it worked!